# Unable to update Hive Transactional table

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to update Hive Transactional table but its giving below error:

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10290]: Encountered parse error while
>   parsing rewritten merge/update or delete query.

Below is my table DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE bucketed_poc(
Col1 Int,
Col2 Int
)
CLUSTERED BY (Col2) INTO 10 BUCKETS
STORED AS ORC TBLPROPERTIES("transactional"="true","orc.compress"="ZLIB");
```

Below are the properties I have set for ACID table:

```
set hive.enforce.bucketing = true;
set hive.support.concurrency = true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict;
set hive.txn.manager = org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager;
set hive.compactor.initiator.on = true;
set hive.compactor.worker.threads = 1;
```

I am able to delete the data but update is not working. I am running below mentioned Update query:

```
Update bucketed_poc set col2 = 1 where `col1=877639`;
```

Answer (score 0):

In hive transaction tables you cannot update the bucketed column. In your case bucketing is done on col2 column, hence you cannot update the col2.